# Assigning names to unnamed labels

Tags: c#, compiler

I'm working on a compiler. During the final stage I will get a collection of `Lines`.

This is the method that takes the `Lines` and gives name to `Labels` that don't have it yet.

`Lines` can have `Labels`. When a `Line` doesn't have a `Label`, its `Label` property is set to `null`. Apart from this, `Labels` can be unnamed (`Label.Name is null`)

This is the method. It looks ugly and I'm using a nested method. Please, review it and try to improve it to be elegant. Performance isn't a requirment (at least, for now):

```
private static void GiveNameToUnnamedLabels(IEnumerable<Line> finalCode)
{
    int count = 0;

    void GiveName(Model.Label label)
    {
        label.Name = $"dyn_label{++count}";
    }

    var unnamed = finalCode.Where(x => x.Label != null && x.Label.Name == null).ToList();
    unnamed.ForEach(x => GiveName(x.Label));
}
```

Comment: I'm not really a fan of slapping a `.ToList()` on LINQ queries just to use the `.ForEach()` method of the `List<T>` class. I would suggest removing it and using a normal `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few notes about your code:

- Both the inner and outer method are fairly small, and the name of the outer method is already aptly descriptive, so I see no need for a named inner method here. An anonymous method would suffice.
- `List<T>.ForEach` is a bit of an odd duck, in my opinion. It looks like functional programming (similar to Linq), but it's actually used to produce side-effects. Combining the two is giving off conflicting signals. A `for` or `foreach` loop, on the other hand, is clearly not functional-style, so side-effects would not be surprising.
- I agree with keeping anonymous method parameter names short, but `x` isn't very descriptive. `line` is a little longer but much more descriptive.

Also, I find it more readable to put chained Linq calls on a line of their own:

```
var unnamed = finalCode
    .Where(x => x.Label != null && x.Label.Name == null)
    .ToList();
```

---

Having that said, I would go for a plain old `foreach` loop. It may not be as fancy, but it's simple and to the point, which should make it easier to understand:

```
int count = 0;
foreach (var line in finalCode)
{
    if (line.Label != null && line.Label.Name == null)
    {
        line.Label.Name = $"dyn_label{++count}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't make a lot of changes.

I don't know which `ForEach` you are using. There are third-party libraries implementing extensions to the standard LINQ extension methods. If you are using one of them, there is no need for `.ToList();`. The `ForEach` can directly work on the `IEnumerable<T>`. Otherwise keep `.ToList()`.

I would let the query return labels, not lines. This enables you to pass `GiveName` as a delegate to `ForEach` without an extra lambda.

I also tweaked the names a little bit and used the new C# 6.0 expression-bodied methods and inlined the temp `unnamed`.

```
private static void NameUnnamedLabels(IEnumerable<Line> finalCode)
{
    int labelNo = 0;

    void GiveName(Model.Label label) => label.Name = $"dyn_label{++labelNo}";

    finalCode
        .Select(ln => ln.Label)
        .Where(lbl => lbl != null && lbl.Name == null)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(GiveName);
}
```

By projecting (`Select`) the line on the label before `Where`, this also slightly simplifies the latter.

Comment: Your first statement is incorrect. `.ForEach()` is not a supplied extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: The signature of `ForEach`  is probably `public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)`. So yes, it works on `IEnumerable<T>`. This does not mean that it is implemented in the base class library.

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever. `.ForEach()` is a method on `List<T>` and no extension method with that signature exists in the standard .NET LINQ libraries. If you're writing it, supply it, otherwise it's useless to the OP.

Comment: There is a `ForEach` operator in `MoreLinq`. Don't know if the OP is using it. I was not aware of the one in `List<T>`.

Comment: Ok, then you should state that as a requirement for your solution to work.